# Disabling Local Notification

Tags: android

For Android Version 4 and above in Settings , we have an option to turn on/off notifications for each application "Show Notification".

Will this option also turn on/off local notifications created by using Alarm Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that setting is likely to disable all notifications generated by that particular app.